# Gradle multi-project with shared logging config

Tags: gradle, log4j, logback, configuration-files

Is there a standard way to share a logging config (for log4j or logback for example) across all sub projects in a gradle project layout?

What I do right now is put a copy of `logback.xml` (or `log4j.properties`) in `src/main/resources` in each sub-project but this results in a lot of unnecessary duplication of this config file

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily overcome using multiple working sets in gradle.

Add a new folder in the root of the project, example "shared-resources" put our configs inside it, and simple add the following line to your `build.gradle` on the sub-project

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/resource", "../shared-resources"]
        }
    }
}
```

This should add both files to your jar file.

An example can be find in [github](https://github.com/Klauswk/maven-crossing-resources)

Comment: Good answer, as an option - this `sourceSets` block can be added to `subprojects` section of `build.gradle` in root project.

Answer (score 4):

Create a shared `util` module containing your `Log4j2` configuration in its `src/main/resources` directory.

Then import the `util` module into others.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":util");
}
```

I also use the `util` module for re-usable Java code, not just for once-off configuration of Log4j2.