# Gradle multi-project build - where to put global resources?

Tags: gradle, log4j, log4j2

I have Gradle multi-project solution looking as the following:

```
---Root
-----SubProject1
-----SubProject2
-----SubProject3
```

In order to avoid duplication, I want to use same log4j2 logger configuration file ("log4j2.xml") for all sub-projects.

is it possible to put it somewhere so it will affect all sub-projects? I prefer solution transparent to each sub-project.

For example, in .NET solution I was able to put log4net configuration into main app.config, and it was applied to all projects in solution. I want to achieve something similar in Java...

Comment: there is a similar question here with a proposed solution  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51991906/6899896

Comment: @M.Ricciuti: this is useful however not transparent to sub-projects (the proposed solution suggests editing build.gradle of each subprojects - something I prefer to avoid)

Comment: I updated my answer based in this proposed solution: you can configure the `sourceSets` directly in the root project build, with no need to update subproject's build scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your subprojects from the root project `build.gradle` script, using the `subprojects` block (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:subprojects(groovy.lang.Closure) )

For example, you can configure the `sourceSets`, in order to append some "shared resources" directory to the subproject's `sourceSets.main.resources` property, as follows:

root project's `build.gradle`

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs += "../shared-resources"
        }
    }
}
```

In your root project you can create a `shared-resources` that will contain all shared configuration files, like `log4j.xml`

Comment: I understand about dependency, but what about configuration file? I referring to "log4j2.xml"